# Problem when One listview uses different Layouts

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I'm experiencing a problem when trying to inflate different type of layouts based on a query on one **list view**. I am using this type so that the entire Activity can be wrapped into one listView and it looks like a scrollable webpage. I'm preferring AdapterView kind of layout because, I'll have to put some huge tables in between, which might get late to load if i inflate using some other kind of Layouts.

I use something like this in the CursorAdapter class

```
public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view = null;
            int viewIndex = cur.getInt(1);
            if (viewIndex == 0)
               view = inflater.inflate(com.sayka.ordergadget.R.layout.takheader, parent, false);
            else if (viewIndex == 1)  {
                view = inflater.inflate(com.sayka.ordergadget.R.layout.activity_order_items2, parent, false);
                if (isNew) passFocus2Name((AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_itemName));
            }
            else if (viewIndex == 2)
                view = inflater.inflate(com.sayka.ordergadget.R.layout.tak_footer, parent, false);
            return view;
        }
```

The problem is that AdapterView seems to inflate views just once. So when I query the cursor, **a null pointer exception** is caught on the BindView method. Cauz this time the adapter is trying to access Layout1 items from Layout2 because previously Layout2 was there in the place of Layout1. I tried to change the view itself if got an error like this

```
public void bindView(View view, Context cont, Cursor cur) {
if (cur.getInt(1) == 2) {
                    TextView totItems_L, totItems_C, totItems, totQty_L, totQty_C, totQty, totAmt_L, totAmt_C, totAmt;
                    TextView testC;

                    try {
                        testC = (TextView)view.findViewById(com.sayka.ordergadget.R.id.totalItemsL);
                        testC.setText("Salim");
                    } catch (NullPointerException exp) {
                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
                        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                        view = inflater.inflate(com.sayka.ordergadget.R.layout.tak_footer, parent, false);
                }
```

here i'm trying to re-assign the view. But its not working. Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to android.

Answer (score 0):

getItemViewType() in your adapter was created for this exact purpose.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount(){
    return NUMBER_OF_TYPES;
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int pos){
    // get your item type
    // return type int, must be less than NUMBER_OF_TYPES
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

Comment: causing exceptions when requery.